# Query on the \pageref command

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, page-numbering

I am trying to use the \pageref command and although it seems to work appropriately and finds the correct page number, for some reason (unknown to me..) it causes big spaces before and after the page number (in every entry). How can I fix that problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: show an example

Comment: In every entry of what? It's not clear what you're asking for. Could you add some more information to your question regarding what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I mean that I am using the \pageref command at the point I need the page number to appear in the text, but there is a huge space before and after the page number when I am making the pdf file. So that it seems ugly... The same happens every time in all other points I wish add the page number by using the \pageref command. Have you ever noticed anything similar to that one?

Comment: What I have done to check it again, was to use another format of a tex file and I then copied and pasted the text to the new file, then compiled into pdf and the new file now gives the correct image without spaces! So, the problem is with the tex file I use. Is there a command I have to use in order to remove the spaces before and after the page number?? (it seems like when we fully adjust a line in the MS Word and if the words are not too many, then the full-adjustment just puts spaces around the words.)

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball guesses you redefine `\thepage` to change the look of your page footer or the spacing of numbers in the ToC, and suggests that you don't do that. As you notice, `\thepage` is also used elsewhere.

(But yes, we need to see an example.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I noticed that the problem is due to the full-adjustment of the paragraph. Even if I am in a proof environment, or in the main text of the document, the problem is the same: there are a lot of spaces before and after the page number... The spaces are then fewer if I write some more words after the pageref point. Is there any idea..???